# Android, Image Button: how to apply different sizes for the foreground and background

Tags: android, background, imagebutton

I want to create a couple of image buttons whose background is a little larger than its foreground. The layout width and layout height only allow me to set a dimension that applies to both the foreground and background.

Many thanks!!

## If this info is helpful:

My activity layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.slideshow.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,HardcodedText" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_home_search"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_home_button_bg_selector"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc_home_search"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/btn_home_user"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/btn_home_interesting"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img_btn_search_normal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_home_user"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="66dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_home_search"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_home_button_bg_selector"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc_home_user"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/btn_home_search"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img_btn_user_normal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_home_interesting"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="66dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_home_search"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_home_button_bg_selector"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc_home_interesting"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/btn_home_search"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img_btn_interesting_normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The selector I referenced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_btn_bg" android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_btn_bg" android:state_focused="true"/>
 <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
 <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: i think you have to make your background image larger than foreground image then is easily solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can Add **android:padding="10dp"** in ImageButton

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of a work around with this. You could do something like this for each button to give it the look that it has a foreground and background of different sizes:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.slideshow.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription,HardcodedText" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/blabla"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/black_semi_transparent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_home_search"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_home_button_bg_selector"
    android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc_home_search"
    android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/btn_home_user"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/btn_home_interesting"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/img_btn_search_normal" />

   </RelativeLayout>

  //....do the same for the other buttons
```

Notice the changes I have made. Basically you would be making a little layout for each button, behind each button, thus giving it a custom foreground and back ground. You can modify it to have images too.

I hope this helps, if not please let me know so I can try something different :)